# ExportTo-CSV does not work properly in PS

Tags: powershell

I'm in the end of creating a simple PS script.
It basically take specific AD user, check which users are directly reports to him and filter these users by prefix EXT then it listing Expiration Date of account and name of these accounts.

I found it difficult to Import these data to CSV file.
Yes, it works but results are more far that what I expect. I should get file filled with Account Names and expiration date of these accounts, instead I got only this:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US7Dx.jpg)

Here is my script

```
$external_users_data = @{}



$if_ext_user = Get-AdUser -Identity xxxx.xxxx -Properties DirectReports | Select -ExpandProperty DirectReports 
ForEach ($user in $if_ext_user) 
    {
        $U = Get-AdUser -identity $user -Property *
            if ($U.UserPrincipalName -like 'EXT.*'){

                Write-Output $U.UserPrincipalName
                Write-Output $U.AccountExpirationDate
                <#$user_object = @{
                    AccountName = $U.UserPrincipalName
                    ExpirationDate = $U.AccountExpirationDate
                    }#>
                    $external_users_data.add($U.UserPrincipalName,$U.AccountExpirationDate)}}
                                                         
                
Write-Host $external_users_data
                   
[ExtAccount_expiration_dates]@{AccountName = $U.UserPrincipalName; ExpirationDate = $U.AccountExpirationDate} |Export-Csv -Append -Path 'C:xxxxxxxxx/csv'
```

for security reasons, I blurred sensitive lines with name of account and file path.
Any ideas are much appreciated.

I'm expecting that final CSV file will be filled with proper data like AccountName and ExpirationDate of that account.

Comment: Your first goal should be to determine whether $external_users_data contains the data you want.  Presumably, that's the reason why you are sending it to Write-Host.  If the answer is yes, what do you get if you just pipe $external_users_data to Export-Csv?

Comment: @WalterMitty By looking into my old script and the one that Dilly provided, now I know where was a mistake. Basically, I was trying to put all data from wrong variable. It should be $if_ext_user not a $external_users_data

Comment: I commented before reading the answer.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSCustomObject available from PS V3.0 or newer. You can use it for better results. For more info please refer [PSCustomObject Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3)
I have no environment to test this code. So, please test it from your end. Hope it works.

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Identity xxxx.xxxx -Properties DirectReports | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports 
$external_users_data = ForEach ($user in $users) {
    $U = Get-AdUser -identity $user -Property *
    if ($U.UserPrincipalName -like 'EXT.*') {

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "AccountName"    = $U.UserPrincipalName
            "ExpirationDate" = $U.AccountExpirationDate 
        }
    }
}     
$external_users_data | Export-Csv -Append -Path 'C:xxxxxxxxx/csv'
```